# compare 2 tables and print similar data

Tags: python, mysql

Consider, I have 2 tables.I wanted to attain similar data from both tables and print respective values.

cars:

```
**abs**
skoda
bmw
benz
```

filename1:

```
No.  v1   v2    v3

1    sport bmw high
2    good audi  medium
3    posh high  benz
```

Problem:Even 2 same values are present in both the tables,its not printing the values in v1 when they have same names: here it ouputs else part even though its true.

Expected Output:

```
bmw
posh
```

Program:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT abs FROM cars")

cursor1 = db.cursor()    
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM filename1") 


for i in cursor.fetchall():    
    for i1 in cursor1.fetchall():
            if i in i1:
                print i1[1]
            else:
                print i[0]
```

Please help! Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: What is it outputting right now?

Comment: its printing else part